# Keyboard shortcut to open drop down box in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I have noticed that doing actions like implementing an interface, that a small rectangle appears at the start of the interface. Then I have to hover my mouse over the rectangle and it becomes a context menu. Then I can select to implicitly implement interface or to explicitly implement interface. Or like when an I type Collection and I need the import of System.Collections.ObjectModel. I get tired of reaching over for my mouse and hovering over the rectangle and waiting for the context menu. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this? If so, please give me every shortcut there is for it. By the way, Visual Studio for me is set to C# development settings, NOT GENERAL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any, or prefer your own, use Tools + Customize, Keyboard and assign keystrokes to the Edit.ImplementInterfaceStubsImplicitly and Edit.ImplementInterfaceStubsExplicitly commands.

Comment: I was just giving an example. I mean open the box for any reason.

Comment: @mohit: View.ShowSmartTag, Shift+Alt+F10 on my (nonstandard) machine.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>